# Please undelete my helpful image

Tags: discussion

Someone posted [a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225344/is-st-always-the-abbreviation-for-saint) about the difference between the abbreviation for "Saint" and "Street". I responded with an image of a street sign for "St. Paul St". The purpose of this image was to clarify that on street signs, the abbreviation for "Saint" gets a period, whereas the abbreviation for "Street" does not. I believe that this is helpful in answering the question. I even got an upvote. But my response was still deleted. Could I please have the support of the community to undelete this post?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the person who deleted your answer, I'd like to point out that the question asks

> ## Is St. always the abbreviation for 'saint'?
>
> [...]
>   Since I never met anyone, before or since, who abbreviated saint [as S.], I am wondering if anyone else ever encountered it?

The question does not ask if there is a difference between the abbreviation for saint and street. Your post does not answer the question.

Comment: Right, but the conversation continued further down about whether people get confused between the two abbreviations, and whether there is a convention about putting a period after one, but not the other. And the question about abbreviating "Saint" as S. was based on the possibility that people could get confused between what the "St" stood for. So the street sign shows how that confusion could be avoided.

Comment: However comments are not part of the question unless they are incorporated into the question. Commenting is a [privilege](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), which you gain after earning 50 reputation points. You should not use the "Your Answer" box to post replies to comments.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that's how the system works. I'll work hard for my 50 points.

Comment: @ghurley - You're accepting the site's system admirably. Welcome!

Comment: @ghurley Now, you got it! Congrats!!